# Matlab: Partly assign numbers into a symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, substitution

I have a matrix with two different symbolic vector variables: S and K
I need to assign numbers to S but not to K. I don't know how to use for subs function in this way. Any suggestions? For example:

```
syms s1 s2 k1 k2 % symbols S and K vector
j1=s1*s2+s1*k1;
j2=k2*s1+k2*k1*s2*s1;
js=[j1, j2];
vars=[s1 s2];
M=jacobian(jcb,vars); % calculate the jacobian here, and the result
% should be a function of s1, s2, k1, k2
```

I need to assign for example s1=2 and s1=3 ans get a matrix which is function of k1 and k2. My real equations have more than 30 variables (s1 .. s30) and about 40 parameters (k1,... k40)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subs`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to perform [multiple substitutions](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#btqh71e-1) at once as follows:

```
subs(M, vars, [2, 3])
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
subs(M, [s1 s2], [2, 3])
```